# Exclude category group from category_archive

Tags: categories, category-group, category-archive

I have the following code below. Trying to show categories from one category group, but instead all categories are being outputted. I've tried using `category_group="1"`, but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
{exp:channel:category_archive channel="speakers" style="linear" backspace="7" category_group="1"}
    <li>
        {categories}
            <a class="btn-open" href="#">{category_name}</a>
        {/categories} 
        {entry_titles}  
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="{path='site/speaker'}">{title}</a></li>
        </ul>  
        {/entry_titles}     
    </li>   
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be an option.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/category_archive.html

I curled and searched that page and found zero references to "Category Group" (case insensitive search). How dynamic is that group? Can you use the `show` parameter and list the categories you want to show?

```
{exp:channel:category_archive channel="speakers" style="linear" backspace="7" show="1|3|5|7|9|666"}
<li>
    {categories}
        <a class="btn-open" href="#">{category_name}</a>
    {/categories} 
    {entry_titles}  
    <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
        <li><a href="{path='site/speaker'}">{title}</a></li>
    </ul>  
    {/entry_titles}     
</li>   
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

I know that is a pain, but sometimes we must develop and play the maintenance game.

**Edit** Thanks for giving me the check; but I'm an idiot and just thought of a much better potential answer!

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/categories.html#variables

Try this parameter! (assuming your cat group is 1):

```
show="{exp:channel:categories category_group='1'}{category_id}|{/exp:channel:categories}"
```

Comment: `show` parameter will just have to do work. Luckily I only have one cat that I don't want to show so using `show="not {category_id}"` will work. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a smarter solution (If it works!!)

Comment: I like the idea, but unfortunately iI'm getting a blank output that way. If you have any other ideas, please let me know!